# DataTables build table from Ajax issue, ok from file, parameter missing? No data available in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have an issue with Datatables populating data from javascript.

If I load the same javascript result from file it works perfectly using the "ajax" attribute in Datatable parameter definition. Have learned that I need to use the "data" attribute instead.

File contains: { "data": [{ "meter": "test", "id": 15, "desc": "testDesc"}] }

This is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dataset = {
        "data": [{
            "meter": "test",
            "id": 15,
            "desc": "testDesc"
        }]
    };
    //var dataset = [  ['test','15','testDesc'] ];            

    $('#MeterDataTable').DataTable({
        //"ajax": 'DataTables-1.10.7/examples/ajax/data/meterDataJsonDown.txt',
        "data": dataset,
            "columns": [{
            "data": "meter"
        }, {
            "data": "id"
        }, {
            "data": "desc"
        }]
    });
    //saveToFile(dataset);
    //  alert('dataset is '+ dataset);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="MeterDataTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>meter</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>desc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>meter</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>desc</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

This works but need to format the jSon javascript returned data by removing the column names.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataset = [
        ['test', '15', 'testDesc']
    ];
    $('#MeterDataTable').DataTable({
        "data": dataset,
            "columns": [{
            "title": "meter"
        }, {
            "title": "id"
        }, {
            "title": "desc"
        }]
    });
});
```

Updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/j5a390d9/

Comment: How come you have headers in both your `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` elements? Just curious.

Comment: Copied as in here https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html#

Comment: Cool. Can you put this together to a JSFiddle so it is easier to see what the error is?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j5a390d9/

Comment: It works right away if you use a newer version, here dataTables 1.10.0 -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4toLj9yn/685/** - so upgrade your dataTables version.

Comment: If my solution helped you, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally a working function as per my initial requirements.

As my jSon returned object contained column name information,
[{ "meter": "test", "id": 15, "desc": "testDesc"}],
 I wanted to use this format as is instead of having to strip down the content as in case order of returned object is altered, the table works just the same.

Haven't got it working in jsFiddle yet. http://jsfiddle.net/j5a390d9/5/
but works ok in my application. Reason for jsFiddle is that I am doing an ajax call to a web service not exposed on internet. Have tried get response from an uploaded file on my website but cannot due to cross site scripting. Tried a proxy but still.

Anyways, this is my working code.

```
var dataset ;

        function meterData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "jSonServices.asmx/getAllMeters",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function (msg) {
                    if ((msg).length < 5)
                        alert("No data Found!");
                    else {
                        //dataset =  [{ "meter": "test", "id": 15, "desc": "testDesc"}];
                        // !important! Parse msg.d string into object                  
                        var obj = JSON.parse(msg.d);                                       
                 $('#MeterDataTable').DataTable(
            {
                "aaData": obj,
                "aoColumns": [
                            { "mData": "meter" },
                            { "mData": "id" },
                            { "mData": "desc" }
                           ]
            }
            );
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("not ok" + e.responseText);
                }
            });    

        }              

        $(document).ready(function () {
            meterData();            
        });
```

Comment: Tks to Loyaler for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your DataTables script is out of date. The old script used a different syntax for loading datatables with data from JavaScript.

Please refer to [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5a390d9/2/) to see your example working - you can use the following version of the DataTables script:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js
```

Comment: This is an alternative working method that I might have used but my array of objects contains the column names. Its another solution though